# How to change link color when hovered over a list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1htet5h1/1/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div id="colors"></div>
    <ul class="navUL">
        <li><span><a href="">NY</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="">CT</a></span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I hover the text link, the background and text color changes but when I hover over the list, the background changes but not the text color.

How can I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SearchForKnowledge Remove The `<span>` tag so that your html code becomes

```
<nav>
   <div id="colors"></div>
     <ul class="navUL">
       <li><a href="">NY</a></li>
       <li><a href="">CT</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

**EDIT:**

updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1htet5h1/3/

Answer (score 0):

In CSS

```
a:hover {    
    color: #(colorCode);
}
s
```

Comment: `a:hover` works but not while you hover over the `LI` only